# What is the Firefall maximum army size?

Tags: firefall

I'm setting up the ranks for my new army, and I'm curious if there's a limit on army size, and what that limit would be. Does anyone know from experience, or have a source that says what the army size is after the game was officially launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in Open Beta, the army cap size was 20 people.

But, between October to December 2013, the maximum number of players you could have in an army was raised to 100 people. It's still the same today.